# Unable to convert Set of Long to another another

Tags: java-8

I have Set of long values. I want to convert it to a List of UserResponse object.
My input is

```
Set<Long> set=new HashSet<>();

public class UserResponse{
private Long updatedAt;

//getter and setter
}
```

Comment: Have you defined any constructors?

Comment: no constructor. Just setter and getter

Answer (score 0):

You can first `stream` the `Set`, then `map` over each element and create a `UserResponse` with the `updatedAt` field set to that element, and finally collect to a `List`.

```java
List<UserResponse> res = set.stream().map(n -> {
    var u = new UserResponse();
    u.setUpdatedAt(n);
    return u;
}).toList();
```

This could be simplified by defining a constructor in `UserResponse` that takes a single `Long` parameter to set as the `updatedAt`.

```java
public UserResponse(Long updatedAt) {
    this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
}
```

Then, a constructor reference could be used for the `map` step instead of a lambda.

```java
List<UserResponse> res = set.stream().map(UserResponse::new).toList();
```